# Using the score method from Sklearn and get ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

sample = np.random.randint(70000, size=5000)
data = mnist.data[sample]
target = mnist.data[sample]

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data, target, train_size=0.8)

knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

error = 1 - knn.score(xtest, ytest)
print('Erreur: %f' % error)
```

when I run "python numb.py" I got this message error:

```
File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 88, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

Comment: sklearn scoring function only support 1D outputs, mnist data are images, therefore 2D. You can try and flatten the output

Comment: @gionni the flattening is already done by fetch_mldata.

Comment: Didn't notice that row, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple typo. `ytest` has the wrong shape, because you should write

```
target = mnist.target[sample]
```

Correcting this, the script runs fine.

Also, the way you build `sample`, you may have duplicates in it, which means some images may be both in test and train set. Consider using `np.random.permutation` to shuffle the order of your samples.
And consider using a seed before calling np.random, to get reproducible results (or better, use `check_random_state` from `sklearn`)

Comment: Thanks P.Camilleri :)